# VBA_Excel Copy from Excel to PPt is not working

Tags: vba, excel

```
  Sub ppt2()
     Dim ppapp As PowerPoint.Application
     Dim ppPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
     Set ppapp = New PowerPoint.Application
     ppapp.Visible = True
     ppapp.Activate

    Set ppPres = ppapp.Presentations.Add
    Set ppslide = ppPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutTitle)
    ppslide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange = "ThisWorkbook"
    Set ppslide = ppPres.Slides.Add(2, ppLayoutBlank)
    ppslide.Select
    Range("A1").Copy
    ppslide.Shapes.Paste
    End Sub
```

The above code `ppslide.Shapes.Paste` produces this error message:

> runtime error 2147188160 shapes.request: Invalid request.CLipboard is empty or contains data which may not be pasted here

Comment: What do you expect it to produce? Some additional context here would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try putting whatever is in Range A1 to a string variable, then putting it into a shape in Powerpoint?

e.g.

```
myString = Range("A1").text
ppPres.Slides("mySlide").Shapes("myShape").TextFrame.TextRange = myString
```

Comment: It is showing error again as runtime error 2147188160 "Item myslide not forunf in the slides collections" for line